# Appending to a select leaks memory JavaScript JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select drop down menu, every time I refresh my page I have to re populate that select drop down. Which is resulting in a memory leak. This is the code any help would be great in refactoring the code. Also I have tried to make another method and calling it before this one, the other method would empty the options array and make it null. That did not help me.

```
    var option = $(document.createElement("option"));
    option.attr("value", List.id);
    option.text(List.name);
        if(List.name.length > maxSize) {
            maxSize = List.name.length;
        }
        this.options.push(option);

        //Mark the currently displayed list as the selected option
        if (activeListId > 0) {
            if (activeListId == List.id) {
                option.attr("selected", true);
            }
        }
    }

    Toolbar.ListSelect.append(this.options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very helpful if you included more of the surrounding code so that we could know what is what, but here's my best shot at it given the current situation.

```
// Reference box
var $box = $('#id-of-select-box');

// Clear select box
$box.empty();

// START LOOP

// Create new option
var $option = $('<option value="'+List.id+'">"'+List.name+'"</option>');

// Append option to select box
$box.append($option);

// END LOOP

//Mark the currently displayed list as the selected option
if (activeListId > 0) {
    $box.val(activeListId);
}
```

Comment: So it is better to append the options in a for loop instead of having a list and appending the entire list at the end ?

Comment: I've never noticed a significant performance hit doing it that way, but it could be done either way.

Comment: @alyn000r I would say no, especially in this case when a reference to `$('#id-of-select-box')` is not saved off. Without saving the reference, you're forcing jQuery to re-traverse the DOM to find the element again before appending it. Definitely build the list and then append it to the element. If you do take this write, save a reference to the element `var $box = $('#id-of-select-box');` prior to entering the loop. Then inside the loop, use the reference rather than the jQuery selector like so: `$box.append($option);`

Answer (score 0):

I whould suggest to create a new  Element, then cut the provided name if exceeds thet maxSize using slice). Later we add the parameter "selected" if there is a match on activeListId and List.id. Latter we append the new option to Toolbar.ListSelect (I suposse it to be the  element

```
var option = jQuery("<option />").attr('value', List.id);
var optionName = List.name.slice(maxSize);
option.text(optionName);
if ( activeListId && activeListId == List.id)
    option.attr("selected", true);
option.appendTo(Toolbar.ListSelect)
```

Comment: Why are we not using this.options.push(option) any more in this ?

Comment: My Code is populating a drop down in a toolbar, the drop down is a selection list, the user can select any page from the drop down and it will display that page.